# from form to owner

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I can get data from owner to form, but not the other way around. 
How can I pass my data from my form to my owner. ?

I really cant not use

```
       Dim ownerFrm As New ownerFrm()
```

If I do that, this form will not load in a database connection and a lot more things, so i'd rather avoid messing with that.
There must be a very simple solution for this. But i just can't come up with it.

Comment: Can you please explain what you exactly want to do here?

Comment: All I want to do is fire a function that is on my owners side and use some properties on the owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner form needs to give a reference to itself to the child form.  There are multiple ways to do this.  For instance, when the owner form shows the child form, it could do something like this:

```
frmChild = New ChildForm()
frmChild.Parent = Me
frmChild.Show()
```

Or, instead of a property, you could overload the child form's constructor:

```
frmChild = New ChildForm(Me)
frmChild.Show()
```

Or, you could create a method that shows the child form and takes the parent as an argument:

```
frmChild = New ChildForm()
frmChild.ShowChild(Me)
```

In all of these cases, the child form must have a variable that keeps a reference to the parent form so that it can make calls back to it.

The other option would be to add events on the child form.  When the child form needs to send data to the owner form, it could raise an event containing the data and the owner form would handle the event and get the data that way.

Comment: i did the third part already, but how am i able to use it on the form/child side ? For example firing an function

Answer (score 0):

You should use events (see [WithEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

Comment: It doesn't need to be `ByRef`.  `Form` is a reference type, so when multiple variables are set to the same value, they all point to the same object.  The only reason to use `ByRef` with reference types is if you need to change the object to which the caller-code's variable is pointing.

Comment: Form may be, but I have no idea what the question wan't passed around. If it was an object, then there's no issue, but if it is a string, it would have to be passed byref so the variable could be modified by the owned form.

Comment: Agreed, although your are confusing things a bit again.  I think what you meant to say was "If it was a reference type, then there's no issue..."  Both reference types (classes) and value types (structures) are considered objects in .NET.  Also, String is a bad example, both because it is a reference type and also because it's designed to be immutable.  So while it's true that you would need to pass a string `ByRef` if you want to modify it, it's not for the reason you state.  The reason is because you need to point the caller's variable to a new string object.